# How to send a test e-mail through postfix using a FQDN instead of localhost?

Tags: server, email, postfix, localhost, gmail

problematic line:

```
MAIL FROM:<nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech>
```

although that could be a side, or even non, issue.

---

Sending success and failure:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ swaks --to nick@saundersconsulting.tech --server localhost
=== Trying localhost:25...
=== Connected to localhost.
<-  220 mordor.saundersconsulting.tech ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
 -> EHLO mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
<-  250-mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
<-  250-PIPELINING
<-  250-SIZE 10240000
<-  250-VRFY
<-  250-ETRN
<-  250-STARTTLS
<-  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<-  250-8BITMIME
<-  250-DSN
<-  250-SMTPUTF8
<-  250 CHUNKING
 -> MAIL FROM:<nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech>
<-  250 2.1.0 Ok
 -> RCPT TO:<nick@saundersconsulting.tech>
<-  250 2.1.5 Ok
 -> DATA
<-  354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
 -> Date: Sun, 17 Dec 2023 06:01:02 -0800
 -> To: nick@saundersconsulting.tech
 -> From: nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
 -> Subject: test Sun, 17 Dec 2023 06:01:02 -0800
 -> Message-Id: <20231217060102.2075937@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech>
 -> X-Mailer: swaks v20201014.0 jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/
 -> 
 -> This is a test mailing
 -> 
 -> 
 -> .
<-  250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A563F44DE
 -> QUIT
<-  221 2.0.0 Bye
=== Connection closed with remote host.
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ swaks --to nick@saundersconsulting.tech --server mordor.bounceme.net
=== Trying mordor.bounceme.net:25...
*** Error connecting to mordor.bounceme.net:25:
***     IO::Socket::INET6: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

log:

```
Dec 17 05:52:30 mordor postfix/smtp[2062947]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c0a::6d]:587: Network is unreachable
Dec 17 05:52:31 mordor postfix/smtp[2062947]: 989AC4464: to=<nick@saundersconsulting.tech>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[172.253.117.108]:587, delay=1, delays=0.05/0.04/0.25/0.68, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1702821151 c2-20020a170902848200b001d09c539c96sm5759678plo.229 - gsmtp)
Dec 17 05:52:31 mordor postfix/qmgr[2062128]: 989AC4464: removed
Dec 17 06:00:39 mordor postfix/smtpd[2074921]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 63: overriding earlier entry: smtp_tls_security_level=may
Dec 17 06:00:39 mordor postfix/postlogd[2074922]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 63: overriding earlier entry: smtp_tls_security_level=may
Dec 17 06:00:39 mordor postfix/proxymap[2074923]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 63: overriding earlier entry: smtp_tls_security_level=may
Dec 17 06:00:39 mordor postfix/smtpd[2074921]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 17 06:00:39 mordor postfix/trivial-rewrite[2074924]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 63: overriding earlier entry: smtp_tls_security_level=may
Dec 17 06:00:39 mordor postfix/cleanup[2074925]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 63: overriding earlier entry: smtp_tls_security_level=may
Dec 17 06:00:39 mordor postfix/smtpd[2074921]: 579F943A0: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 17 06:00:39 mordor postfix/cleanup[2074925]: 579F943A0: message-id=<20231217060039.2074920@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech>
Dec 17 06:00:39 mordor postfix/qmgr[2062128]: 579F943A0: from=<nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech>, size=541, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 17 06:00:39 mordor postfix/smtpd[2074921]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Dec 17 06:00:39 mordor postfix/smtp[2074926]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 63: overriding earlier entry: smtp_tls_security_level=may
Dec 17 06:00:39 mordor postfix/smtp[2074926]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c0a::6d]:587: Network is unreachable
Dec 17 06:00:41 mordor postfix/smtp[2074926]: 579F943A0: to=<nick@saundersconsulting.tech>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[172.253.117.109]:587, delay=1.9, delays=0.03/0.03/0.98/0.84, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1702821641 oe16-20020a17090b395000b0028b21d24ba6sm5180708pjb.15 - gsmtp)
Dec 17 06:00:41 mordor postfix/qmgr[2062128]: 579F943A0: removed
Dec 17 06:01:02 mordor postfix/smtpd[2074921]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 17 06:01:02 mordor postfix/smtpd[2074921]: A563F44DE: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 17 06:01:02 mordor postfix/cleanup[2074925]: A563F44DE: message-id=<20231217060102.2075937@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech>
Dec 17 06:01:02 mordor postfix/qmgr[2062128]: A563F44DE: from=<nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech>, size=541, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 17 06:01:02 mordor postfix/smtp[2074926]: connect to smtp.gmail.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c0a::6d]:587: Network is unreachable
Dec 17 06:01:02 mordor postfix/smtpd[2074921]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Dec 17 06:01:04 mordor postfix/smtp[2074926]: A563F44DE: to=<nick@saundersconsulting.tech>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[172.253.117.109]:587, delay=1.9, delays=0.03/0/0.72/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1702821664 f11-20020a17090aec8b00b0028ae8284840sm8565076pjy.10 - gsmtp)
Dec 17 06:01:04 mordor postfix/qmgr[2062128]: A563F44DE: removed
```

although I did notice in the received e-mail:

```
X-Google-Original-From: nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
```

Regardless, sending through localhost is fine.  Why is it not possible to specify the FQDN for the localhost as it's the same machine.

```
mydestination = $myhostname, mordor.saundersconsulting.tech, localhost
myhostname = mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
myorigin = mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
```

so that I'd expect postfix to parse the FQDN the same as entering "localhost" for the server.

--

on a side-note, I'm seeing:

Be careful with this message

> This may be a spoofed message. The message claims to have been sent
> from your account, but Gmail couldn’t verify the actual source. Avoid
> clicking links or replying with sensitive information, unless you are
> sure you actually sent this message. (No need to reset your password,
> the real sender does not actually have access to your account!)

from my own messages.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu.  I'm not on that machine, but fairly recent version.